# WSA Action property in envelope header

Tags: soap

Is there any possibility to add action property in envelope header of a soap request?
I'm trying to build below envelope in apex using generated class from WSDL, however
the property <wsa:action > is missing. I've tried to add custom code to the generated class in order to put <ws:action > in a header but without results.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <env:Header>
        <Security xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <UsernameToken>
                <Username>XXXX</Username>
                <Password>XXXXXX</Password>
                <Nonce>NDUxOTQ3NDg1Njk4MjU4NjI0MA==</Nonce>
                <wsu:Created>2023-08-14T10:27:38Z</wsu:Created>
            </UsernameToken>
        </Security>
        <wsa:Action xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://tempuri.org/ITerytWs1/WyszukajMiejscowosc</wsa:Action>
    </env:Header>
    
    <env:Body>
        <m:WyszukajMiejscowosc xmlns:m="http://tempuri.org/">
            <m:nazwaMiejscowosci>City</m:nazwaMiejscowosci>
        </m:WyszukajMiejscowosc>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful